CSS selector within a class or id that targets only one filetype
I'm new to CSS (VERY new, third day), and have searched high and low for someone who had this same query, but I haven't found anything. So far I've tried making a class or an id for an image, and within that class/id I want one specific filetype (.gif) to vary in size from the other image types. I'm pulling my hair out, I can't figure out how to select any instance of the filetype, as opposed to a specific gif.
I've tried :target, but I'm not sure how to target a filetype as opposed to an url with a specific name.
My latest effort was this (I've also tried giving jpgs and pngs the same specific code above the gifs with the same content, but it didn't work):
.items {
        clear: both;
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 200px;
            height: auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
        margin: 5px;
        img[href*='.gif'] {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 80px;
                height: auto;
            max-height: 100%;
            object-fit: contain;
            margin: 5px;
        }
}

What I was expecting was that all images within that class would have one style, EXCEPT gifs, which have another style. What I get is the .items class applied, but not the gifs selector. So, is it possible to select just .gifs within this class?
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, or if it's simply not possible to include this in a class, or what? I have a script folder for javascript, but no idea how to write any if necessary (it's there with some legacy code for swapping images that someone gave me 20 years ago). My file structure is:
named folder
index.html
subfolder: _CSS
_name-of-folder styles.css
_name-of-folder scripts.js
subfolder: name-of-folder images/cast/items
imageX.jpg
imageY.png
imageZ.gif

nesting selectors won't work unless you're using some CSS preprocessor like Sass/SCSS. In plain CSS it would be .items img[src$=".gif"] which would select nested img tags with srcs that end with .gif within elements with the items class

I tried removing the nested gif selector and placing it outside the .items class, so that first there's the .items class and then the .items img[src$=".gif"] class, but this didn't work. Did I do it wrong?

Is the items class on the img itself or is img nested? Check your browser dev-tools to see what CSS styles are being applied as well to your img tags to see if you can see things overwriting your styles.

The solution below seemed to work, except it doesn't restrict itself to the class. The inspector shows that the code below applied as-is simply isn't used, and defaults back to the general img styling for the sheet.

Is the items class on the img itself or is img nested within an items class?

The items class is within the html code for the image itself. I tried changing where it was placed, before or after the src, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

@NickParsons I didn't fully understand your comment about nesting - CSS nesting is available in a lot of the common browsers now (albeit in some cases with slightly different syntax than some preprocessors).

@AHaworth oh yes you’re right, I stand corrected, thanks for pointing that out

If I use this code, it works so long as I don't mind all gifs on the page being styled this way (a bit irritating), and so long as I put class="img, items" in that order on each image loaded.
.items {
clear: both;
display: flex;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
max-width: 200px;
height: auto;
max-height: 100%;
object-fit: contain;
margin: 5px;
}
img[src$=".gif"] {
width: 100%;
max-width: 80px;
height: auto;
max-height: 100%;
object-fit: contain;
margin: 5px;
}
If anyone knows how to constrain it...

You can select html object with attribute equal to something with
img[src="something"] {
    /* Your styles here */
}

But as you need to select only by file extension, you can use $= as shown below
img[src$=".gif"] {
    /* Your styles here */
}

As for your code:

mistake one: you're using *= which will check if .gif is mentioned anywhere in string,but you need to use $= to check if .gif is in last
mistake 2: css doesn't support nested selection, and you seem to use default css: so corrected code will be like:





.items {
    clear: both;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin: 5px;
}

.items img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 80px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin: 5px;
}

/*This targets only GIF images within .items*/
.items img[src$=".gif"] {
    border: 2px solid red; /*Example style for GIFs..*/
}
<div class="items">
    <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
    <img src="image2.gif" alt="Image 2">
    <img src="image3.png" alt="Image 3">
    <img src="image4.gif" alt="Image 4">
</div>



Code sandbox preview/example: https://87y63l.csb.app/

This doesn't appear to work unfortunately. The gifs are still being styled as the other image filetypes.

have you place items img[src$=".gif"] below .items img ? also try !important

The code example worked! Thank you so much!

Oops, I guess it didn't work after all - if I use the last snippet of code it works correctly, except it doesn't restrict itself to the .items class. If I use the code as you posted, it doesn't work at all. :/

I have added html code(no change in css) in codesandbox,and added demo link(you can see code as well in codesandbox) everything works as expected. If you implemented exactly this,i need more context to help(maybe something else is overriding), or you can check difference between my code in codesandbox and your

I copied and pasted your code, and added one div with the class name and nothing in the img tags, and another div without the "items" class, and added the class to each img instead, and nothing is working - it also doesn't seem to work in the sandbox, the non-gif images are gigantic? I don't understand what's going on, I checked in Chrome and Firefox but it's the same. I'll see if I can understand how to use the sandbox with all the code I have to show you.

the first four images are in item div, and two of them are red in sandbox, the vertically arranged gigantic images are outside div and they get no styling,so they are big. I cant make the html code again, if you face problems,fork my codesandbox,change html,and share link

I tried updating the code on your page with mine, now it seems the class .items size doesn't apply to anything, only the gif size? https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/eager-meadow-forked-7t4z22?workspaceId=c33a6f0b-fc23-4b96-925a-7754934e2024

@redoc the common browsers do support CSS nesting now.

Oh,I didn't know that. Thanks

Thanks so much for your help, guys, and especially you, redoc! I think I figured it out through this kluge: I just specified the size for each filetype. Now they're constrained to the div with the class "items", and each image has the correct size and position. :D
.items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 2px solid blue; /*Example style for div..*/
}

/*This targets only JPG images within .items*/
.items img[src$=".jpg"] {
  border: 2px solid green; /*Example style for jpgs..*/
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center bottom;
  margin: 5px;
}
/*This targets only PNG images within .items*/
.items img[src$=".png"] {
  border: 2px solid blue; /*Example style for jpgs..*/
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
    object-position: center bottom;
  margin: 5px;
}
/*This targets only GIF images within .items*/
.items img[src$=".gif"] {
  border: 2px solid red; /*Example style for GIFs..*/
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center bottom;
  margin: 5px;
}


wish you the best : )
